# Issue with app bundle when upload the app bundle on google play console

Tags: google-play-console, intentfilter, google-developers-console

`I try to upload app bundle on the google play console but this message appears "You've uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that has an activity, activity alias, service, or broadcast sink with intent filter, but without setting the android:exported property. This file cannot be installed on Android 12 or later. See developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported".`

I try adding intent filter to each activity with intents but did not work, adding exported to each activity as well but this second did not working.

Comment: Make sure you add "android:exported=true" to all services, activities, etc. If it still doesn't work, then can you include a copy of your manifest?

Comment: here is the manifest https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MDt9Xwq4FQzoglVwxreekMlnt3CXoAQkGPmCKtydPFI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you depend on any library that have their own activities or services? Check the merged manifest in the intermediate build files

Comment: i checked merged manifest but i did not found errors there